# Randomly select increasing subset of data to see where mean levels off

Tags: subset, montecarlo, spss, sampling, mean

Could anyone please advise the best way to do the following?

I have three variables (X, Y & Z) and four groups (1, 2, 3 & 4). I have been using discriminant function analysis in SPSS to predict group membership of known grouped data for use with future ungrouped data.

Ideally I would like to able to randomly sample an increasing number of a subset of the data to see how many observations are required to hit a desired correct classification percentage.

However, I understand this might be difficult. Therefore, I'm looking to to do this for the means.

For example, Lets say variable X has a mean of 141 for group 1. This mean might have been calculated from 2000 observations. However, it might be the case that the mean occurred at say 700 observations. I would like to be able to calculate at what number of observations/cases the mean levels of in my data. For example, perhaps starting at 10 observations and repeating this randomly say 50 or 100 times, then increasing to 20 observations....and so on.

I understand this is a form of monte carlo testing. I have access to SPSS 15, 17 and 18 and excel. I also have access to minitab 15 & 16 and amos17 and have downloaded "R" but im not familiar with these. My experience is with SPSS and excel. I have tried some syntax in SPSS Modified from this..http://pages.infinit.net/rlevesqu/Syntax/RandomSampling/Select2CasesFromEachGroup.txt but this would still be quite time consuming on my part to enter the subset number ect etc.

Hope some one can help.

Thanks for reading.

Andy

Comment: R is pretty nice for doing this sort of stuff. If you see yourself doing more of this sort of thing in the future, it is worth learning how to use it. If I was using R, I would take random a whole bunch of random subsets of a group, with the subsets ranging in size from small to large, and calculate their mean. Then I'd plot them all on a graph of mean / subset-size, and see if they were converging to anything. The implementation of this would be pretty simple in any real programming language, but its hard to do in excel-like programs.

Answer (score 1):

The text you linked to is a good start (you can also use the `SAMPLE` command in SPSS, but IMO the Raynald script you linked to is more flexible when you think about constructing the sample that way).

In pseudo-code, the process might look like;

```
do n for sample size (a to b)
    loop 100 times
        draw sample size n
        compute (& save) statistics
```

Here is where SPSS's macro language comes into play (I think [this document](http://szoc.tarstud.hu/upload/szoc_szakirany_programmingwithspsssyntaxandmacros.pdf) is a good introduction, plus you can examine other references on the [SPSS tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spss/info)). Basically once you figure out how to draw the sample and compute the stats you want, you just need to figure out how to write a macro so you can loop through the process (and pass it the sample size parameter). I include the loop 100 times because you want to be able to make some type of estimate about the error associated with each sample size.

If you give an example of how you compute the statistics I may be able to give examples of how to make that into a macro function and loop through the desired number of times.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy W
@Oliver

Thanks for your suggestions guys. Ive managed to find a work around using the following macro from.........http://www.spsstools.net/Syntax/Bootstrap/GetRandomSampleOfVariousSizeCalcStats.txt     However, for this I need to copy and paste the variable data for a given group into a new data window. Thats not to much of a problem. To take this further would anyone know how: 1/ I could get other statistics recorded eg std error, std dev ect ect. 2/Use other analysis, ideally discriminant function analysis and record in a new data window the percentage of correct classificcations rather than having lots of output tables 3/not need to copy and paste variables for each group so I can just run the macro specifying n samples for x variable on group 1, 2, 3 & 4.

Thanks again.

```
DEFINE !sample(myvar !TOKENS(1) 
        /nbsampl !TOKENS(1)
        /size !CMDEND).
* myvar = the variable of interest (here we want the mean of salary)
* nbsampl = number of samples.
* size = the size of each samples.

!LET !first='1'
!DO !ss !IN (!size)
!DO !count = 1 !TO !nbsampl.

GET FILE='c:\Program Files\SPSS\employee data.sav'.

COMPUTE draw=uniform(1).
SORT CASES BY draw.
N OF CASES !ss.

COMPUTE samplenb=!count. 
COMPUTE ss=!ss.

AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=*
  /BREAK=samplenb
  /!myvar = MEAN(!myvar) /ss=FIRST(ss).

!IF (!first !NE '1') !THEN
ADD FILES /FILE=*  /FILE='c:\temp\sample.sav'.
!IFEND
SAVE OUTFILE='c:\temp\sample.sav'.
!LET !first='0'

!DOEND. 
!DOEND. 

VARIABLE LABEL ss 'Sample size'.
EXAMINE
  VARIABLES=salary BY ss /PLOT=BOXPLOT/STATISTICS=NONE/NOTOTAL
  /MISSING=REPORT.

!ENDDEFINE.
* ----------------END OF MACRO ----------------------------------------------.


* Call macro (parameters are number of samples (here 20) and sizes of sample (here 5, 10,15,30,50). 
* Thus 20 samples of size 5.
* Thus 20 samples of size 10, etc.
!sample myvar=salary nbsampl=20 size= 5 10 15 30 50.
```

Comment: I don't have the time right now to give specific examples, but if you look up `OMS` in the help section it will give examples of saving output to new files (including new .sav datasets). Essentially anything that goes into the output can be saved in a new SPSS dataset.